# Trying to Create a new Policy for Multi Disk Operations

Tags: clickhouse

I am using clickhouse with just one disk which is specified at config.xml file under `<path>`

Now I want to extend this disk, so I updated the clickhouse version for enabling multi disk support.

What I want to do now is using the two disks together. I want to read from both of them but write data to second one only.

I have many tables, I thought changing the storage policy of the tables would do the trick but i can't change it.

For example i have a table called default_event which has default policy, after this query:

```
alter table default_event modify setting storage_policy='newStorage_only';
```

I got this error `: Exception: New storage policy` default `shall contain volumes of old one`

My storage xml is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yandex>
   <storage_configuration>
      <disks>
         <!--    
    default disk is special, it always    
    exists even if not explicitly    
    configured here, but you can't change    
    it's path here (you should use <path>    
    on top level config instead)    
    -->
         <default>
            <!--    
    You can reserve some amount of free space    
    on any disk (including default) by adding    
    keep_free_space_bytes tag    
    -->
            <keep_free_space_bytes>1024</keep_free_space_bytes>
         </default>
         <test_disk>
            <!--    
    disk path must end with a slash,    
    folder should be writable for clickhouse user    
    -->
            <path>/DATA/newStorage/</path>
         </test_disk>
         <test_disk_2>
            <!--    
    disk path must end with a slash,    
    folder should be writable for clickhouse user    
    -->
            <path>/DATA/secondStorage/</path>
         </test_disk_2>
         <test_disk_3>
            <!--    
    disk path must end with a slash,    
    folder should be writable for clickhouse user    
    -->
            <path>/DATA/thirdStorage/</path>
         </test_disk_3>
      </disks>
      <policies>
         <newStorage_only>
            <!-- name for new storage policy -->
            <volumes>
               <newStorage_volume>
                  <!-- name of volume -->
                  <!--    
    we have only one disk in that volume    
    and we reference here the name of disk    
    as configured above in <disks> section    
    -->
                  <disk>test_disk</disk>
               </newStorage_volume>
            </volumes>
         </newStorage_only>
      </policies>
   </storage_configuration>
</yandex>
```

I tried adding default volume to the new policy but i can't start clickhouse with that config.

Answer (score 3):

So, your main problem is that before that you did not explicitly specify the storage policy, but the `default` disk is written there by default. New policy should include all old disks and volumes with same names.

I gave a configuration based on yours, removing everything unnecessary. And that, I mean that in addition to those listed, you have a drive specified in `path` with the name `default`. All disks are listed in the `volumes` section of the new policy. Writing to new disks will happen thanks to `move_factor`. The value 0.5 tells us that when 50% of the disk space is reached, we need to write to the next one, and so on.
As soon as the rest of the disks fill evenly, you can lower this value.

PS: you can not use old disks in the new policy, for this you need to execute `ALTER TABLE ... MOVE PARTITIONS/PARTS ...` to transfer partitions/parts to new disks. Then the table will not be tied to the old disk and it will not be tedious to specify it in the new storage policy. Disks, of course, must be pre-configured in the settings.

```xml
<yandex>
  <storage_configuration>
    <disks>
        <test_disk>
            <path>/DATA/newStorage/</path>
        </test_disk>
        <test_disk_2>
            <path>/DATA/secondStorage/</path>
        </test_disk_2>
        <test_disk_3>
            <path>/DATA/thirdStorage/</path>
        </test_disk_3>
    </disks>
    <policies>
        <!--... old policy  ... -->
        <new_storage_only> <!-- policy name -->
            <volumes>
                <default>
                    <disk>default</disk>
                </default>
                <new_volume> 
                    <disk>test_disk</disk>
                    <disk>test_disk_2</disk>
                    <disk>test_disk_3</disk>
                </new_volume>
            </volumes>
            <move_factor>0.5</move_factor>
        </new_storage_only>

    </policies>

  </storage_configuration>
</yandex>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my clickhouse version was older than 19.15, i read this multi disk support was released later versions. So i had no policy set before, everything was default. I upgraded clickhouse version and i am trying to make this work right now. After firing up clickhouse with the xml you shared, i still can't change the policy of existing table. Same error. You said i can't use the old disk in the new policy, did you mean for data writing to it? I only need this disk for reading now. How am i gonna use this new policy for current tables?

Comment: @İlkerDemirci 
On the contrary, you must use the old `volumes` and old `disks` classes in the new policy. Both, if you did not change, will have the name `default`. I made changes in mxl